# Can I fix this accidental abstract shape without removing it?

Tags: modeling

I'm currently doing my first modeling project without a tutorial and I accidentally made a cool abstract shape to it by dragging wildly with the Bevel tool (I think).

[image: Described shape in the middle. Happened after subdividing the lateral faces of a cylinder and using bevel in an exaggerated manner.]

[image: As you can see by the wireframe, the structure is a whole mess there.]

Thing is, I don't really know how to give depth to the walls of the cylinder, which is a regular cylinder except for the abstract part, without destroying everything in the process. Solidify doesn't work at all without throwing around visual glitches. I want to know if there's any way I could fix this without removing the messy abstract faces. Maybe simplifying all those faces into a simpler shape without losing appearance for the renders?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: images are helpful. as of now people have to download a file to understand what you are talking about. Please [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/182277/edit) and add an image or two.

Comment: @Timaroberts pics are up!

Comment: I hate to be the one to break it to you, but your "cool shape" is full of overlapping faces resulting in massive Z-fighting and shading artifacts, That is also why you cannot solidify the geometry without glitches, unfortunately,

Comment: @ChristopherBennett alright. It seemed so, but I was hoping there was a way of making the shape simpler and keeping its looks, somehow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Usually, you can use a decimate modifier, maybe in conjunction with merge-by-distance, but I tried on yours, and you have to decimate A LOT before it even becomes workable ane even then there  are still overlaps. Probably better to start again with simpler geometry. However, I have some free time later, I might try and "re-create" your shape with proper geometry. If I get it to work, i'll post it here.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'd immensely appreciate it if you did! Thanks man.